# Two-finger panning with WM_POINTER based touch

Tags: c++, windows-8, touch, multi-touch

I'm working on Windows 8, c++, with the WM_POINTER touch mechanism (and context interaction callback). My question is - how can I differentiate between a zoom operation and a two-finger pan operation?

Thanks,
yakobom

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, if you are using this low-level mechanism, you need to do the "math" yourself. You need to detect each pointer separately (each has an id) and figure out where they are in relation to one another. After you calculate distance, deltas etc, you can make assumptions as to what the user was gesturing.

WM_GESTURE gives you the ability to detect higher-level touch events (zoom, pan) and does the calc for you:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd353242(VS.85).aspx

As far as I know, WM_GESTURE and WM_TOUCH are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Hi Shahar,Thanks for your answer. Actually, I'm well familiar with WM_GESTURE and I'm migrating from it now, since in some aspects it's not as good as WM_POINTER. I know that WM_POINTER requires me to track the pointers and do the math, and I do that - but from some reason I'm having practical difficulties in distinguishing the zoom and the two finger pan. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hi Shahar, do you have some experience with any of the touch APIs?

Comment: I have done some things with custom multi-touch gestures. Not a lot. What issues are you running into?

Comment: If you're asking about WM_GESTURE, the main problem is responsiveness.  in WM_POINTER, the problem is that sometimes it's hard to calculate the exact gesture. And the documentation and samples on context interaction is quite poor...

Comment: Was asking about WM_POINTER. If you have any specific questions, I can try to help - I did a little work there. One thing you can actually do is look at old Windows Phone Silverlight Toolkit code - there's a gesture manager there that essentially generates WM_GESTURE-like events (if I remember correctly - I may be off). It may give you some ideas on how to do it yourself if I am remembering correctly.

Comment: Currently my only question is the one I started with. Thanks for the tip - I'll take a look at the toolkit code. When you say "Old toolkit" you mean what version?

Comment: It's the 7.1 version. The component was deprecated, but is still in it. What I was asking is - what issues do you have with discerning between the two? On most clients I tried, when you pan with 2 fingers, small fluctuations with resizing occurs in scale as well. Can you elaborate on the issues you are having?

Comment: Yes, this is what I was experiencing. I couldn't tell if it's 2 fingers panning since I also got scaling data... The problem is - I don't really know who to ask. It does not seems like many people use it...

Comment: 2 finger panning can be looked at as "pan while zooming" instead. Then it becomes obvious that it's "acceptable" behavior. if that's what you are seeing, I think that it should be fine. You can also work out some threshold, but then there'll be a jerk in scaling when a user start resizing, so I don't think it's worth it. But do two-finger panning on IE10, iPad, the Windows 8 start screen - you will notice that the system will resize your view as well.

Comment: yeah, well, this will not work for me. I'll need to try and find the way. Toda!